# Tensorflow GPU installation Ubuntu 16.04 Error (libcuda.so not found)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cuda, tensorflow, cudnn

I have installed the gpu version of tensorflow but when I try to import it I get the following error message:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:116] Couldn't open CUDA library libcuda.so.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: sep-GS60-2QE
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: Permission denied: could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1066] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1067] failed to find libcuda.so on this system: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcuda.so.1; dlerror: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.367.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
```

I have followed the installation guide from the tensorflow website, and have made sure that I have installed Cuda and CudNN correctly.

I have tried creating sym-links from a `libcuda.so` that I found in my system to the cuda directory as suggested on other posts on the nvidia's website as well but they did not help.

I have also set the parameters in ~/.bashrc to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}"`and `export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda"` but still no luck :( .

It would be most helpful if anyone could help me get this sorted as it is a crucial part of my project to run the code on my gpu.

Comment: do you actually have an NVIDiA GPU and have you installed the driver?

Comment: yes, I do. I have also checked if my GPU is compatible with Tensorflow, which it is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` you typed, and tensorflow read. I see that you have `usr/local/cuda...` instead of `/usr/local/cuda` (Note the `/` in the beginning of the path)

Usually, for me the following LD_LIBRARY_PATH is sufficient after installing cuda using the runfile installer from nvidia.
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: It's true that the path has a typo, but: 1. Other libraries on that path were found successfully and 2. libcuda.So is not on that path. It is installed separately by the driver installer.

Comment: As @RobertCrovella mentioned it does find other libraries but not Libcuda.so and it is true that file is not on the path, but I have ran the command 'sudo find /usr/ -name 'libcuda.so.1' ' for the various libcuda.so# that it needs, found and have created a sym-link for them in that path.